# Find all ring homomorphisms from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My question is find all homomorphism $ f: \Bbb Q \to \Bbb R$.

I think I should use ring isomorphism theorem to do this problem, but I just don't know how to do this.

Comment: Not a duplicate if the OP really means homomorphisms from $\Bbb Q$ to $\Bbb R$ and not from $\Bbb Q$ to any ring $R$, since the former case is significantly easier. Maybe he could clarify.

Comment: yes I means homomorphism from rational number to real number

Comment: Oh I see the more powerful conclusion.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924060/ring-homomorphisms-from-bbb-q-into-a-ring

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the above link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A homomorphism $f$ must satisfy

$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$
$$f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$$
$$f(1)=1$$

Thus for integer $n$, $$f(n)=f(1+\dots+1)=f(1)+\dots+f(1)=nf(1)=n$$

Hence $f(n)=n$.

Also, for coprime integers $p,q$,

$$f(q\cdot p/q)=f(q)f(p/q)=qf(p/q)=f(p)=p$$

Thus $f(p/q)=p/q$.

Conclusion?

Comment: so the only homomorphism is trivial hom?

Comment: @VitoChou There is only the [inclusion map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_map).